# Java character IO, specifically writing to a file

Tags: java, file, input

So I have a reader writer as such:

```
File f2 = new File("thisfileexists.txt");
BufferedReaeder reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 10000 * 1024);
PrintWriter fos = new Printwriter(new FileOutputStream(f2));
```

and a reading loop later in the program

```
List<Integer> compressed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String l;
while((l = reader.readLine()) != null){
    compressed.add(Integer.parseInt(l)); //assume only valid integer values
}
```

later on when I go

```
String result = "";
for(int k : compressed){
    String entry;
    //affect entry here

    fos.write(entry);
    result += entry;
}
```

the file that fos is writing to is empty after the loop finished executing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual homework part of the assignment, only to the printing of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you close your `FileOutputStream`?

```
String result = "";
for(int k : compressed){
  String entry;
  //affect entry here

  fos.write(entry);
  result += entry;
}

fos.close();       // close the file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing the file when you finish? Without

```
fos.close();
```

The end of the file can be lost. If the file is small enough all you get is an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you closed the stream after all data is written? :)